# Magento 2.2 How to add product sku to order confirmation email?

Tags: magento2, sku, order-confirmation

I am working on a new site using Magento 2.2. This is my first project using Magento 2. Can anyone guide me how to add the product SKU to the order confirmation email?

When I go to **Backend -> Marketing -> Email Templates -> edit** the New Order Confirmation Template, I saw this  `{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}` which will output the order product details. But I am not sure which file I should edit to add the product SKU, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml` to your theme

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml

Now add sku `<td class="item-sku"><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getSku($_item)) ?></td>` where you want to show sku

**I added sku after product name here is final `default.phtml`**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\DefaultItems */

/** @var $_item \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */
$_item = $block->getItem();
$_order = $_item->getOrder();
?>
<tr>
    <td class="item-info<?php if ($block->getItemOptions()): ?> has-extra<?php endif; ?>">
        <p class="product-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></p>
        <?php if ($block->getItemOptions()): ?>
            <dl class="item-options">
            <?php foreach ($block->getItemOptions() as $option): ?>
                <dt><strong><em><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $option['label'] ?></em></strong></dt>
                <dd>
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  nl2br($option['value']) ?>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $addInfoBlock = $block->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
        <?php if ($addInfoBlock) :?>
            <?= $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
    </td>
    <!-- Here add sku column --> 
    <td class="item-sku"><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getSku($_item)) ?></td>
    <td class="item-qty"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getQtyOrdered() * 1 ?></td>
    <td class="item-price">
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $block->getItemPrice($_item) ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php if ($_item->getGiftMessageId() && $_giftMessage = $this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->getGiftMessage($_item->getGiftMessageId())): ?>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="item-extra">
        <table class="message-gift">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h3><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Gift Message') ?></h3>
                    <strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('From:') ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?>
                    <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('To:') ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?>
                    <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Message:') ?></strong>
                    <br /><?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getMessage()) ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Also you need to override `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml` for add new  for sku

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items.phtml

```
<th class="item-qty">
    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Sku') ?>
</th>
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image]

Comment: Do you happen to know how to add a product attribute by attribute code to the email as well?

Comment: @PrincePatel So if I want to add **my_sku** attribute in email then can I use **$_item->getMySku();** ?

Comment: @PrincePatel Okay. That **$_tem->getId()** will return item ID or product ID ?

Comment: `$_item->getProduct()->getId();` will return the product ID.
`$_item->getMySku()` will **NOT** return the value of the product attribute my_sku. I am actually working on add the product attribute to the email. No luck for now. I will keep you updated here once I find out.

Comment: @KishanPatadia I have checked $_item object and it has `[product_id]` So you can get product id by `$_item->getProductId()`

Comment: @PrincePatel Yes. I have also checked it and used getProductId() method.

Comment: I try above code but not working.. It showing blank email